# Are there any Spreadsheet apps that are as easy and powerful to use as Vim?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vim

I'd like to use a spreadsheet that lets me move around cells like I do in Vim.

As well, the more commands that are attributed to keyboard shortcuts, the better. Particularly stuff like making Text-to-Columns which is one of my more frequently used features in Excel.

I don't mind learning the shortcuts if they allow me to just look at the spreadsheet page and forget about everything else.

edit: The way I am thinking about the Spreadsheet right now is as if every cell is its own unique file. There should be a command where I choose to open that file and edit it right on the spot within the view of the spreadsheet. So I guess I want different modes like in vim which have commands and there should be one mode that is hooked up just to do operations or formatting which would be similar to command mode in Vim.

Comment: I don't quite get what you're after. Customizable keyboard shortcuts or different modes?

Comment: Software recommendations a re off topic at superuser

Comment: I think I understand what you mean; like for instance, wouldn't it be nice to save a cell as a bookmark the way you do in vim; or have several clipboard buffers?

Answer (score 2):

With Libreoffice/OpenOffice you can [customize your keyboard](http://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Shortcuts_Accessibility). That should enable you to move about with the same effortless speed that you can do with vim.

(Personally I would write a vim plug-in that used [Excel::Writer::XLSX](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX.pm) or Spreadsheet::WriteExcel to extract the spreadsheet and then present a read-only screen that covered the whole terminal except the last line, where I would have the active cell. Then it is just a matter of adding commands to select areas of the page and the other useful functions.)

Comment: It appers that someone has creates a macro file to make excel respond to vi(m) movement commands - https://github.com/kjnh10/ExcelLikeVim.